# Callback After Dapp Approval

Tags: web3js, javascript, dapps, calldata

I have had a contract made for me, and a dapp set up by a developer.

My question is how can i produce an event on my website when the user has approved spend of a certain token?

Can i use a javascript code to pick up that user has approved a certain contract/token via metamask and then display a pop up "You have successfully connected your BEP-20 Token"

I have tried the following.

```
async function connect_wallet(redirect_url) {
  /** Checking if a metamask extension is available and trying to access it.....of course with the user's permission */
  let web3_obj = get_web3_object();

  try {
   
    var accounts = await web3_obj.eth.requestAccounts();

    // redirects the user to the home page.
    if (accounts) {
      // showing a success message to the user and update wallet balance
      window.alert(`${accounts} Connected Successfully`)
      // show_wallet_info(accounts[0]);

      // saving the account in local storage
      localStorage.setItem('account', accounts[0]);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (error["message"] == "Already processing eth_requestAccounts. Please wait.") {
      // start_loader("")
      window.alert("You seem to have denied access to a previous attempt to access your wallet, please clarify that.")
    } else {
      // start_loader("")
      console.log("An Error Occured.")
      console.log(error)
      // window.alert("An Error Occured.")
    }
  }
}

async function checkconnect_wallet {

web3.eth.on('approval', async (from, spender, amount, token) => {
  // Check if the approved token address and amount match your criteria
  if (token === '0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955' && amount >= 1000000) {
    // Display a pop-up message using JavaScript
    alert('You have successfully connected your BEP-20 Token!');
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use JavaScript along with the Web3.js library to listen for a 'Approval' event emitted by your BEP-20 token contract. Once the event is detected, you can trigger a pop-up on your website.

```
web3.eth.on('approval', async (from, spender, amount, token) => {
  // Check if the approved token address and amount match your criteria
  if (token === '0xYourTokenAddress' && amount >= 100) {
    // Display a pop-up message using JavaScript
    alert('You have successfully connected your BEP-20 Token!');
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi i have tried this but it will not pop up, i have added the code to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is using `wagmi` on your dapp. It makes pretty easy to watch transaction confirmation and straight forward. Here is an example using `wagmi react`. There are several `hooks` assist your transactions.

```
const { data, isLoading, isSuccess, write } = useContractWrite({
   address: <ERC20 Address>,
   abi: <ERC20 ABI>,
   functionName: 'approve',
})

const approve = () => {
    write({
      args: [<Amount>],
      from: <Callee>,
    });
}
```

Now you can use `isLoading`, `isSuccess`, `data` inside your compenents. In here you can use `isSuccess` `boolean` value to show the message.

Ref: https://wagmi.sh/react/hooks/useContractWrite